# Mongoose heartbeat and reconnect don't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

the automatic reconnection function natively embedded in mongoose does not work on my project.

I actually receive a return in error but it does not start again after the X seconds that I configured.

Beyond whether the credentials are correct or not, I expect mongoose to try to log in every X seconds (and therefore send me a log each time) but it is not

Here is the doc in question: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options

Here is my code:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const options = {
    dbName: "testbdd",
    pass: "qwe",
    user: "alex",
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 1000,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 1000,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}
const uri = `mongodb://localhost/`



mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log('Mongo db disconnected!');
});

mongoose.connect(uri, options).then(() => {
    console.log('First Mongo db connexion success !')
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('First Mongo db connexion fail !')
    console.log(error)
})
```

Here is the return when I run the node server:

```
backend_1  | Mongo db disconnected!
backend_1  | First Mongo db connexion fail !
backend_1  | MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
backend_1  |     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/user/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:800:32)
backend_1  |     at /user/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:341:10
backend_1  |     at /user/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
backend_1  |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
backend_1  |     at promiseOrCallback (/user/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
backend_1  |     at Mongoose.connect (/user/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:340:10)
backend_1  |     at Object.connect (/user/app/src/db/mongo/index.js:28:10)
backend_1  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
backend_1  |     at Module._compile (/user/app/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:99:24)
backend_1  |     at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
backend_1  |     at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/user/app/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
backend_1  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
backend_1  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
backend_1  |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
backend_1  |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
backend_1  |     at Object.require (/user/app/src/bin/www.js:7:1) {
backend_1  |   message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017',
backend_1  |   reason: TopologyDescription {
backend_1  |     type: 'Single',
backend_1  |     setName: null,
backend_1  |     maxSetVersion: null,
backend_1  |     maxElectionId: null,
backend_1  |     servers: Map { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
backend_1  |     stale: false,
backend_1  |     compatible: true,
backend_1  |     compatibilityError: null,
backend_1  |     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
backend_1  |     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 1000,
backend_1  |     localThresholdMS: 15,
backend_1  |     commonWireVersion: null
backend_1  |   }
backend_1  | }
```

Those options should work well, no ?

```
serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 1000,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 1000,
useUnifiedTopology: true
```

I am really lost. I doubt it's the mongoose code that doesn't work, it's necessarily my implementation.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the intended behavior of the mongodb driver

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-834?focusedCommentId=1412582&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-1412582

> The driver will fail on first connect if it cannot connect to the host. This is by design to ensure quick failure on unreachable hosts. Reconnect behavior only kicks in once the driver has performed the initial connect.

Comment: Yes I figured it out later ... Thanks for the reply.

In order to correct my problem anyway and possibly help other people here is how I proceeded:

1 / I created a function that connects with mongoose.

2 / At the disconnect event I used a timeout which calls the connection function.

This works fine for the first failed attempt and then mongoose options handle in case of connection loss.